# Путь к файлу процесса c#

Tags: c#, процесс

Получаю список процессов

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process[] procList = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
```

Как узнать папку, где находится этот процесс ? 
Пытался так

`procList[0].MainModule.FileName`  - возвращает `null`

`procList[0].StartInfo.FileName`  - возвращает пустую строку

Есть еще способы ?

Comment: Писал под себя диспетчер задач ) Остался исходник там есть и путь к программе и прочее может поможет: [NTaskManager](https://mega.nz/#!NjRFXaDC!0Eqjmw40UgdUXLxlqpS154Pv-Qkb31VmEaAg8_ubKFY)

Comment: А Вы хотите получить путь к файлу процесса от куда запускаете или всех процессов?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить так: `Console.WriteLine(Process.GetProcesses()[0].MainModule.FileName.ToString());`

Comment: Используйте WMI [так, как показано здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/c-how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process)

Comment: @СтаниславПечезеров да, вродь подходит, спасибо большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если Вам нужно получить путь программы откуда запускаете свой файл:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

try
{
  foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => 
                      !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle)).ToList())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(proc.MainModule.FileName); 
  }
}
catch { /*Тут ловим исключения*/ }
```

Так же без использования `Linq`

```
Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

Имя запускаемого файла можно узнать так:

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName));
```

Чтобы перечислить все папки через процессы можно воспользоваться таким способом:

```
foreach (Process instance in Process.GetProcesses())
{
  try
  {
     Console.WriteLine(instance.ProcessName);
     Console.WriteLine(instance.MainModule.FileName);
  }
  catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception w32ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(w32ex.Message);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Если же Вы хотите получить все папки процессов можно воспользоваться через WMI

```
using (var mCollection = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process").GetInstances())
{
  foreach (ManagementObject process in mCollection)
  {                            
    Console.WriteLine((string)process["ExecutablePath"]);      
    //Console.WriteLine(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo((string)process["ExecutablePath"]).FileDescription);                     
  }
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял пример, то код выведет не все процессы

Comment: @Lolidze, Верно) Но если Вам нужно вывести все процессы используйте WMI - вот как пример: [List Windows active processes in C#](https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/c-list-windows-active-processes/)

Comment: @Lolidze, Обновил ответ